# Parallelize loop operation with Google Data Flow

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to run an ARIMA Model with thousands of CSV files with various combination

Using Pyflux 
Here is some python code..

```
index =0
#filename has file names of thousands of files
for csvfile in filenames:
data = pd.read_csv(csvfile)
model = pf.ARIMA(data=data,ar=4,ma=4,integ=0,target='sunspot.year')
x = model.fit("MLE")

list_of_results[index] = list_of_tuples[index] + (x.summary(),)

index++
```

I can load these CSV's in Big Query and want to parallelize this operation of sending the data into the ARIMA model as the operation of running the data through ARIMA model with these Files or BigQuery result can run in parallel so that I can save significant time on this operation.

Is there a way to achieve this in Google Data flow?

Answer (score 0):

If all the CSV files are on GCS, you should be able to create a simple pipeline that reads them from GCS, and runs your model on each element in parallel.

See the documentation on `ParDo` for processing all the elements in parallel: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do

Comment: The ARIMA library is available in Python and R..is there a way for using ParDo in Python? or using R on Dataflow..

Comment: got ParDo on python will try it https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#transforms-pardo

Comment: You should note that Apache Beam splits computation in multiple processes, so you will have a separate ARIMA model for each process (in fact, for each bundle). You will need a way of merging the models into one, or a way to use the different models separately.

Comment: @Pablo   see you are from Dataflow team...I don't see any detailed tutorial by Google on Youtube which explains Dataflow concepts from scratch for someone who is new to it.My data is on big query and am able to query and modify it with python/pandas..It would be great if you can point a good resource which makes DataFlow understanding easier other than the googles documentation..or ask your team to make one..the presentations give overall concept but I would like to see a run through of code with all the major concept of Pipeline PCollection PTransform and I/O source and sync

Comment: Here's a demo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UfZN59Nsk8
Do you find that useful?